# Eclipse not finding library files in lib folder. I imported a project folder

Tags: java, spring-mvc

[image]All my files in the WebContent shows error

[image]

this is the error on running the project

Comment: Try pressing ctrl + shift + T and type in the name of the class to check whether it is available in the classpath or not...

Comment: Why u have a cross mark on lib folder?